# Add a javascript value to a Freemarker list

Tags: javascript, freemarker

I need to add  values from a javascript function  to a freemarker list

Example : 
I pass from my controller to the view an object,schoolObject.
schoolObject has a List attribute called classNames

Is it applicable to add values to this list from a javascript !!

The following doesn't work :

```
function addclass(className){ 
    var name=document.getElementById(smth).value.trim();
    document.getElementById(classNames).value=name
    alert(document.getElementById(classNames).value);
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the goal of freemarker and javascript.

Javascript is a client language. It allows you to add dynamic behavior on a page which is already rendered by the server.

Freemarker is a template language which allows you to format an html page on the server before it is rendered.

So, you can't fill a freemarker list with javascript but you can fill this list with a list coming from server code.

Once the page is rendered to the client, freemarker is not used anymore, only your javascript is used...

Comment: So I guess that to handle this is to pass this java script array to the server using ajax and the server would set this list into a bean . Is there a way to facilitate this via JQuery !!

Comment: it depends on your case. If you need to save the list to display it again, yes save it on database. If you only need to change a form list depending on another value, use javascript to dynamic change the list : but freemarker is not used here !

Comment: I have 2 more question : 1 - If I have javascript array , could I render it on the freenmarker page 2- Is there anyway that this javascript array can be passed to the controller in some how !!

Comment: Like I've said in my post, javascript is not a server side language. You can send datas to server (but call it json array, not javascript array) and use this data in freemarker or other server side language. To do that, use ajax, post or get request.

Comment: Hello ,interesting talks where. @Jerome what about pass some json array to javascript. how to you pass such object from freemarker to a javascript method as its argument for example.thanks